# Thermophilic yoghurt bacteria survivability in the gut

Tags: fermentation, gut-bacteria, thermophilia

Would they mostly not simply perish since they need much higher than body temperatures to thrive? Are mesophilic ones (such as kefir) much better at that and thus have better probiotic functions?

Comment: I had magnesium supplements for a while because i was deficient, but their alkaline pH upset my gut and I had gas. Afterwards, I tried all kinds of cheese and yoghurts, olives and whatever fermented food i could find. They had nearly zero probiotic action. one day i had fermented taboulet salad from a pack that had puffed up from fermentation. I was completely better for a week, Since then i decided that cheese has very little probiotic effect and that a soup that was purposefully left on the counter for days until it goes biological has incredible probiotics.

Comment: Milk contains no cellulose and plant matter, so if you eat plants, a fermented equivalent of milk, unpasteurized/fermented plant matter, should logically provide probiotics more adapted for humans. Milk products are a good contribution to diet but it's a myth that they are contain a suitable mix of probiotics for all people, they are probably most effective for digesting protein. cheese yeasts can thrive between 0-43 degrees and diverse cheeses contain a bigger diversity of species.

Comment: I have been questioning the usefulness of commercial yoghurts stored, sold and served chilled. And @comprehensible, your point well taken, unless there is a lactose and caesin rich diet, these poor mircrobes will only starve and suffer in the gut if they had not already died of cold.